# LLVM emulation in java library?

Tags: java, llvm

Just wondering out of curiosity, if one exists ?

Comment: Do you want to execute LLVM bitcode from Java application? Easiest way would be to write thin JNI wrapper providing you functionality you need - leaving all the LLVM jit or interpreter invocation in native ode.

Comment: @mrtis-mozeiko from what i can tell there are many similarities between instruction sets, i was hoping someones done the hard/boring work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a project called [java-lli](http://code.google.com/p/java-lli/) on GoogleCode that seems to be trying to do this.  It is not clear how much progress has been made though.  (No downloadable artefacts, and nothing in the Wiki.  Just stuff in SVN with the last commits in May 2011.)

FWIW, you get more results if you search for "interpreter" rather than "emulator".

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, the project you mention never seemed to get very far. However its still interesting to browse.

Answer (score 0):

Just for further information, David A. Roberts put together [LLJVM](http://da.vidr.cc/projects/lljvm) ([@Github](https://github.com/davidar/lljvm)). This project is also for executing LLVM-derived bitcode on the Java JVM.

Please refer to [my SO answer regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934707/is-it-possible-to-transform-llvm-bytecode-into-java-bytecode#13540256), as some other community members had furthered his code/created patches.

[Update] - [LLJVM](http://da.vidr.cc/projects/lljvm) has seemed to have been dead for somewhile, however Howard Chu (https://github.com/hyc) looks to have made [LLJVM](http://da.vidr.cc/projects/lljvm) compatible with the latest version of LLVM (3.3). See [Howard's LLJVM-LLVM3.3 branch at Github, here](https://github.com/hyc/lljvm/tree/llvm3.3)